# PS4 controller only working wired in games on WIN10

Tags: controllers, windows-10

I've been using my PS4 controller wired on Windows 10, but it's not too comfortable.

I tried on several occasions to get it running wireless but to no avail. I have successfully connected it to my PC using a Bluetooth adapter, and it shows as connected and it is lit up, but it doesn't work in-game. Only works wired.

I have tried using DS4Windows (the new one that's maintained), but the problem with that is that it makes it be recognized as an Xbox360 controller, changing all the prompts in-game to Xbox controls.

Is there a way to get it to work in games wirelessly with or without DS4Windows while also keeping it visible to the game as a PS4 controller?.. The 'DInput only' option in DS4Windows only works wired.

Comment: I had this issue too, but got used to it being wired as a controller. I use Antimicro from GitHub and I never needed to worry about it assigning Xbox 360 controls.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue before, so I used [Xpadder](https://www.xpadder.com/)*.

It is a great software for programming input on your controller so that games on the PC recognise the DS4 input. It will allow you to use your PS4 controller on PC if you're playing steam or using emulators.

<sub>* I have no affiliation with the software or the team surrounding it.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You should try downloading Steam and running the game through it. You will have to add the game to Steam library and configure your PS4 controller into steam controller settings.
Here is how to add the game to steam library.
https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2219-YDJV-5557

Comment: I've already tried that but it still changes all prompts ingame to Xbox controls.